# Aggregating row types using attributes found in subsequent rows

Tags: count, row, forward

I have a analysis table that looks as shown below. Row 1 is associated with rows 2 and 3. Row 4 has no associated rows. Row 6 is associated with rows 6, 7, 8.  I want to summarize this table using Name as the ID and bycounting Attr1 entries.

```
> d     
        Name    Attr1   Attr2  
1       C2H2            Organic
2               5       A       
3               9       B       
4       C4H4                
5       C4H6
6               22      B
7               36      
8               94      B
```

where some analyses have full or (C2H2, C4H6) partial set of attributes defined (Attr1, Attr2) and some analyses (C4H4) do not have any attributes known.I want to count the number of named compounds by counting the Attr1 sub category. i.e I want to end up with a count a la:

```
1     C2H2  2   
2     C4H4  1  
3     C4H6  3
```

To achieve this count accurately, there is a need to look at attributes in subsequent rows to compute the count. How best is this done?

Comment: Can you provide the schema for this table? You are looking for a simple `group by`, if my understanding of the question is correct, but answering it needs a bit more details about the structure, otherwise is just a wild guess.

Comment: Ok I misread the fact that groups with no data known should count as 1.

Answer (score 0):

An attempt at a wild guess based on assumptions of the structure of your table is the following. Please let me know of any differences so I can correct accordingly.

The code below assumed Postgres. This should work with minimal changes on most databases.

Assuming the data:

```
create table chem (
    name text, 
    attr1 text, 
    attr2 text
);

insert into chem (name, attr1, attr2) 
values 
    ('C2H2', null, 'organic'), 
    ('C2H2', 5, 'A'), 
    ('C2H2', 9, 'B'), 
    ('C4H4', null, null), 
    ('C4H6', 22, 'B'), 
    ('C4H6', 36, null), 
    ('C4H6', 94, 'B');
```

The query:

```
select name, count (1)
from chem
where attr1 is not null
group by name

union

select name, 1
from chem fa
where not exists (
    select 1
    from chem fb
    where fa.name = fb.name
        and attr1 is not null
    limit 1)
```

Produces as result:

```
"C4H4";1
"C4H6";3
"C2H2";2
```